# Split a string with python re

Tags: python, regex, string, stdin

I'm reading a file from std input a line at the time with python and every line is in the following format:

```
Id:0\t1.0,0.0,83,212,302,475\n
```

where `\t` stands for tab and `\n` for new line. I would like to use python `regex` to parse it and obtain a list containing all and only the numbers of the string.

```
E.g. ['0','1.0','0.0','83','212','302','475']
```

Can you please tell me how to implement this in a one-liner?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
my_str = 'Id:0\t1.0,0.0,83,212,302,475\n'

re.findall('[\d\.]+',my_str)
Out[144]: ['0', '1.0', '0.0', '83', '212', '302', '475']
```

You could alternately do it like this:

```
[x.strip('Id:\n') for x in re.split('[\t,]',my_str)]
Out[143]: ['0', '1.0', '0.0', '83', '212', '302', '475']
```

But that's a little fragile (and harder to read)

Comment: This is as smooth as it could ever get! Thanks a lot...Can I pleas ask you to explain me how the magic works?

Comment: I would recommend compiling the RegEx, if it is used more than once.

Comment: @thefourtheye - what do you mean?

Comment: @Matteo Basically: match characters that are a digit or a decimal (`[\d\.]`).  Greedily match (`+`) as many of those characters as possible .  Return all such matches in a list.

Comment: @thefourtheye that is unnecessary.  The `re` module caches the last 100 compiled regex.

Comment: @roippi Quoting from the [docs](http://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#module-contents) `Note: The compiled versions of the most recent patterns passed to re.match(), re.search() or re.compile() are cached, so programs that use only a few regular expressions at a time needn’t worry about compiling regular expressions.`

Comment: @thefourtheye so you... agree with me?  Or do you think that `findall` somehow uses a different compilation schema than the rest of the module?  (it doesn't)